# my php is causing my page to break

Tags: php, web

I am in the process of redesigning my portfolio and am trying to use new knowledge from when I first made the site. I am struggling with something however and am hoping someone could answer my question.

The below php is causing my website to break.

Sorry what I mean by break is, it was causing to page to not load at all.

```
<?php if ($page=="home") {
                      echo '<h2 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".7s">Modern, Bespoke and Affordable Web Design</h2>';
                      elseif ($page =="prices")
                      echo '<h2 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".7s">Affordable Web Design Packages for all your needs</h2>';
                      elseif ($page =="projects")
                      echo '<h2 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".7s">Beautiful, Bespoke projects from a range of clients</h2>';}
                      elseif ($page =="contact")
                      echo '<h2 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".7s">Contact me to make your business shine</h2>'
                    }
                    ?>
```

Comment: Try adding a final else condition

Comment: How does it break? Please make sure you read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: as in, stopping the page from loading.

Comment: either wrap each line in brackets or remove them from the outer

Comment: What do you mean by break? As in split in two? Not working at all? No error messages? You need to specify what happens

Comment: Just a tip: enabling php error messages when developing will automatically give you answers to those type of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code like this,

```
<?php if ($page=="home") //{ Remove brace
                      echo '<h2 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".7s">Modern, Bespoke and Affordable Web Design</h2>'; 
                      elseif ($page =="prices")
                      echo '<h2 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".7s">Affordable Web Design Packages for all your needs</h2>';
                      elseif ($page =="projects")
                      echo '<h2 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".7s">Beautiful, Bespoke projects from a range of clients</h2>'; //}Remove brace
                      elseif ($page =="contact")
                      echo '<h2 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".7s">Contact me to make your business shine</h2>'
                    //} Remove brace
                    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you ! 

This is the first piece of php I have written myself, off top of head and without reading books etc. I got close lol :D #

Comment: Welcome, feeling happy to help you:)

Comment: If I could tick two answers I would but I am unable to, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You had misplaced braces in code

```
if ($page=="home") //{ removed from here
    echo '<h2 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".7s">Modern, Bespoke and Affordable Web Design</h2>'; 
elseif ($page =="prices")
    echo '<h2 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".7s">Affordable Web Design Packages for all your needs</h2>';
elseif ($page =="projects")
    echo '<h2 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".7s">Beautiful, Bespoke projects from a range of clients</h2>'; // } removed from here
elseif ($page =="contact")
    echo '<h2 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".7s">Contact me to make your business shine</h2>'
//} removed from here
```

You have started here

```
if ($page=="home") {
```

and ended after second `elseif`

and another `}` at last

You should use better IDE

Comment: Yep, at line 6 : `clients</h2>';}`

Comment: Fantastic, well spot!,

and the braces should have been after the end echo?

Comment: It is now working perfect and I see my error. Thank you !

Comment: Welcome, glad to help you :)

Comment: @JonFuller When your page break you should always check your brackets. Just click on one bracket and the closing one will be hovered so you can see that it's at the right position

Comment: What do you mean better IDE?

Comment: Editor which you use to type code, the error you had faced would be shown by editor itself